# are all elements of ZpxZp in ECC definite over Zp

Tags: elliptic-curves, prime-numbers, finite-field, cryptocurrency

are all elements of ZpxZp in ECC (elliptic curve) definite over Zp ?

otherwise: assume G a base point of ECC and n the order of G.

why n is equal or nother to p*p ? (p a prime number).

(Think to a Bitcoin Curve: y^2 = x^3 + 7).

Answer (score 1):

All points have two coordinates.
Both coordinates lies in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (I'm assuming a curve defined over $GF(p)$).

But not all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ are valid points for an elliptic curve. Only those which verifies the curve's equation.

So if you select all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and call the first $x$ and the second $y$, and when you put them in (for example) $y^2 = x^3 + 7$ if you obtain an equality, then your $x$ and $y$ form a valid point belonging to your curve.

If you count them (and add the point at infinity, which is a special point who can't be represented as $(x,y)$), their number will be the cardinality of the curve, which is a number related to your $p$ through [Hasse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) but can be smaller or bigger.

Comment: True. I only make a mistake in the equation that I have updated to the right one: y^2 = x^3 + 7